# React Native non-serializable values were found in the navigation state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to build an app and pass parameter to between pages. so i'm using to navigation. here PageOne code:

```
const PageOne=({navigation})=>{
...
onPress={_ => { navigation.navigate("PageTwo", { navigation }) }}>
```

PageTwo codes

```
const SettingsPage = ({route}) => {
const {navigation} = route.params
```

my code is working. i mean, i can use the navigation but getting yellow alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you are trying to pass a callback or something that is not serializable as a param when navigating to a new screen.
in this case you don't don't need to pass navigation as a param, so replace this:
`navigation.navigate("PageTwo", { navigation })` with `navigation.navigate("PageTwo")`

and in your SettingsPage, just do the following

```
const SettingsPage = ({route}) => {
const navigation = useNavigation()
```

or

```
const SettingsPage = ({route, navigation}) => {
// you can get navigation from props if the component is a screen
```

Comment: thank you  so much!! i wanna ask one more question. when i add a page in to stack screen so that mean i can use `useNavigation()` there

Comment: yeah, you can use it in any screen, and also in any component if that component is a children of the screen

Answer (score 0):

@RodSar' answer really helps me, after a long troubleshoot. so i add this one, saving little time for anyone who needs :

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

you should import `useNavigation` before you can use it, as @Rodstar mentions :

```
const SettingsPage = ({route}) => {
   const navigation = useNavigation()

   return ... // your codes here, as usual
}
```

I wanna comment @RodSar but have not enough reputation, so i made this one new answer instead.

### **SECOND METHOD**

```
const SettingsPage = ({route, navigation}) => {

   return ... // your codes here, as usual
}
```

or you can also destructure them like this

```
const SettingsPage = properties => {
   const {route, navigation, yourAnotherProps} = properties

   return ... // your codes here, as usual
}
```

the result will be same.
**AND ALSO** you can type it with your `properties.route.params` if you're passing parameters from previous screen

```
const SettingsPage = properties => {
   const {route, navigation, parameter1, parameter2} = properties.route.params

   return ... // your codes here, as usual
}
```

as far as what i tried, all working fine as long as you

### don't pass any navigation as params, where-ever it is

no more `non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state` yellow warn. thanks to @RodSar.